# How to add table and image on the same line using docx?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

now i try to generate docx which using python-docx library, and my question is i want to known how to add the table and image locate at on the same line like the example below.

[image]

And this is my code.

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=3, cols=3,style='Table Grid')
document.add_picture('graph.png') 
document.save('test.docx')
```

The result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would require "floating" items (floating table and/or floating chart), neither of which have API support in `python-docx` yet.