# python-docx how to add space before/after a table

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a table defined in python-docx. To add a bit of space before/after that table, I'm just using an empty paragraph. That's ok but I would like to add a half/line worth space instead of a full line's worth of space.

Found these:

- http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/a-w_topFromText-1.html
- http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/a-w_bottomFromText-1.html

Both are part of tblpPr:

- http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_tblpPr-1.html

These seem to do exactly what I want. But I haven't been able to figure out how to add those attributes.

I have tried:

`tbl._tblPr.set(qn('w:bottomFromText'), '1440')`
Note the tbl._tblPr is defined and accessible in Python but it does not generate any extra space. Note the units for 1440 are "twentieths of point".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as you have pointed out `tblpPr` are properties of Floating Table Positioning. Does your table have floating positioning?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64098248/how-to-add-table-and-image-on-the-same-line-using-docx 
floating tables are not available in python-docx as of a couple years ago.

"This would require "floating" items (floating table and/or floating chart), neither of which have API support in python-docx yet." (posted by scanny)

I'm using style "Table Grid" if that helps.

Is there another OOXML that I can use for non-floating tables?

Comment: just tried introducing a few floating table properties to make it work, it's really messi :) here's what i have, https://pastebin.com/2RLiQhMy, but here's working example of table xml should look like: https://pastebin.com/M8YY79se my guess is that you'd need to set missing attributes on table rows/cells so word would know how to position stuff. i resolved your case with empty paras as well. good luck!